Future date transform to user timezone failed
enter code hereI am trying to make a function that parse event date and present it to use based on his timezone. SO this is the function:
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import utc from "dayjs/plugin/utc";
import timezone from "dayjs/plugin/timezone";
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

export const parseEventDate = (
  timeZone: string,
  eventData: {
    date: string;
    time: string;
    timeZone: string;
  }
) => {
  const eventDateTime = `${eventData.date} ${eventData.time}`;

  const gathering = dayjs.tz(eventDateTime, eventData.timeZone);

  const eventInLocalTime = gathering.tz(timeZone);

  const formattedEventTime = eventInLocalTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

  return formattedEventTime;
};

This is how I test it:
log(
      "DATE 1",
      parseEventDate("Europe/Belgrade", {
        date: "2024-08-21",
        time: "16:00",
        timeZone: "Europe/Belgrade",
      })
    );
    log(
      "DATE 2",
      parseEventDate("America/New_York", {
        date: "2024-08-21",
        time: "16:00",
        timeZone: "Europe/Belgrade",
      })
    );

But instead of date time presented in timezone of the user I get for both: "2024-08-21 14:38".
I bang my head whole morning on this.
If it's important I am using this in react-native and I am getting user timezone from phone but in this case (1st parameter) I hardcoded it to test.
Second parameter is object that contain information about event when and in what timezone it's saved.
It should be different for New_York.

Note: Nobody knows about future dates. We had cases of changes with very few days notification (Venezuela). -- To solve the problem usually we distinguish "wall time" to other times (universal time, elapsed/difference time, etc.). If a country remove summer time: what do you need to change? 16:00 remains constant or the UTC time remains constant? (or the number of seconds from now, so maybe one second earlier of later because of leap second)
